# SharePoint app 502

Tags: sharepoint-addin

My SharePoint app is giving me a 502 error.  The app was successfully added to the site.  I added the app url (app-{Appid}.apps.server) to the HOSTS file and pinged the domain, I get a response back from 127.0.0.1 from app-{Appid}.apps.server.  I'm trying to hit the URL from the server by clicking on the app from site contents.  At first I thought I was getting a 404 error but when I open Fiddler to check the response, it actually turns out that I get a 502 error (bad gateway) after the 302 redirect from appredirect.aspx. I'm merely testing with HOSTS before I set everything up in DNS.  Neither the site nor web app is using Host Headers.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think what you are missing is what you say you are missing: to actually create the app domain in DNS

Comment: Shouldn't it work locally if I add the address to the HOSTS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, it was just a proxy server issue.  Disabling the proxy fixed it.